# Positive adverbs for negative verbs?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Some verbs have senses that are somehow positive. For example, consider

```
protected
sheltered 
supported
```

And thus the opposites of these verbs has the related negative senses:

```
unprotected
unsheltered
unsupported
```

On the other side, some adverbs have senses that are somehow positive. For example, consider:

```
fully
completely
perfectly
```

Now, when we use these positive adverbs with those verbs that have the positive senses, it sounds natural:

```
perfectly protected
fully supported
```

To the contrary, when we use such positive adverbs for those verbs that have negative senses, it sounds unnatural:

```
perfectly unprotected
fully unsupported
```

**Is there anything unidiomatic about such usages? And, if so, how do we usually avoid them?What adverb can we use for example for "unprotected" to means "perfectly unprotected"?**

Comment: "The spectacle was *splendidly terrible* to the watchers in Boston." - "The Battle of Bunker Hill" by [Stephen Crane](https://books.google.com/books?id=FlFDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA930&dq=%22splendidly+terrible%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid5KzB9pPVAhVBWz4KHd7cBY8Q6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=%22splendidly%20terrible%22&f=false)

Comment: You are also sort of venturing into the territory of oxymoron like usages or things that are very similar to them. An oxymoron is not always illogical. It's more like a play on words. A good example is Jumbo Shrimp. Technically it's an oxymoron. How can it be huge and small at the same time? But it just means it's the largest variety of something we know to be small (it's not *actually* illogical). What you are talking about above is on very similar ground (different but still similar).

Comment: It's like doing terrible wonderful things to someone's body. We see in this and other examples here that such oil & vinegar lends itself to satirical use. The contradiction produces an interesting mix.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So any suggestion for which adverbs to use in such conditions?

Comment: *protected, sheltered, supported* are neutral. They can have either a positive or negative meaning depending on their use and context. Also  saying *perfectly unprotected, fully unsupported* does not sound unnatural. Therefore I think this question is opinion-based and too broad.

Comment: I am **totally** unprotected and unsupported. Supremely unqualified for the job. Awesomely bored to tears. Extravagantly vanilla personality. *Quickly* stop me now.

Comment: Your question suggests that "completely", being *positive*, would not work with negative verbs like "unprotected". But that is a great word to use "completely unprotected" is completely idiomatic.

Comment: Both **totally** and **completely** are degrees on a spectrum of *doneness/undoneness* rather than *positivity/negativity*.

Answer (score 3):

In *At Dawn We Slept*, [Gordon Prange's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Prange) definitive work on Pearl Harbor, he has some excellent quotes from military men with strongly expressed opinions.

I recall one of them describing a colleague as **perfectly useless**.  So it's definitely possible to use these expressions idiomatically, especially in a context where "negative" things like weakness or isolation are seen as desirable by an attacker, or by people whose thoughts run along these lines.

Comment: Yes, but that is an idiosyncrasy of _perfectly_ which has a (rather old-fashioned) use as an intensifier, meaning _completely_, separate from is primary meaning related to _perfect_.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm suggesting more generally that "positive" and "negative" are subjective concepts that depend on the point of view being represented by the author, and that the combination of a positive adverb with a negative verb is fairly common, just as it is in expressions like a **pious fraud** or **honor amongst thieves**.

Comment: @GlobalCharm I don't think he was was chiding you. He was just pointing out that oddness of perfectly. I agree with you as well.

Comment: @Kace36 Apologies to you and ColinFine (only one notification per post, I've just discovered).  I'm a big fan of Gordon Prange, and I used his book as an example even though there are probably better examples out there.  Sorry for sounding defensive.

Comment: @Kace36 So do you have any adverb to suggest for use in cases like "perfectly unprotected" where "unprotected" is taken as negative?

Comment: @Sasan "completely", "totally" etc.